# vscode on MacOS: getting navigation menu to show up in a full screen mode

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get vscode show navigation menu i.e Code|File|Edit|... and the project name in a full screen mode on MAC. It's almost impossible to see the name of the project when having multiple instances of code open in full screen mode.

Answer (score 2):

v1.42 has a new option that may help:

> Controls if native full-screen should be used on macOS. 
>    Disable this option to prevent macOS from creating a new space when going full-screen.
>
> ```
> "window.nativeFullScreen": true,
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not what the full screen mode is made for. If you go full screen you are supposed to work almost exclusively in that application (only occasionally switching to other apps like mail, e.g. via command+tab). You can always have the menu bar (and the window title) appear when you move the mouse pointer to the top of the screen, however.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the project is visible in the file explorer.

In this example, the project name (i.e. root folder) is `testgit`
[image: file explorer]

You can always quickly show the file explorer using the keyboard shortcut `Shift-Cmd-E`.